# What is the difference between a wildcart certificate and a chained certificate for a subdomain?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Newbee SSL cert question.

Background:
I purchased a simple domain validation certificate from Comodo and got 4 certificates which I had to chain manually. The certificate costs 10USD.

A wildcart certificate cost more like 100USD.

Question: Is it not possible to create a certificate request for any subdomain myself and then sign the .csr with the purchased domain certificate and then chain everything together?

There *must* be some logic error in my understanding otherwise there would not be such business model, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There must be some logic error in my understanding otherwise there would not be such business model, would it?

The logic error is that you assume, that you could use the certificate you bought to sign other certificates. But, signing other certificates is only possible for certificates with a special flag and certificate agencies (CA) like Comodo will not sell you such certificates (or only for lots of money and a security audit).

The main reason for this restriction is that (because of a broken design) any CA certificate could be used to sign any host certificate, which means once you own a trusted CA certificate you would be able to impersonate all other hosts.

BTW, a wildcard certificate has also the chain. The only difference to the cheaper certificate is that it is valid for more hosts (e.g. all subdomains of a domain).

Comment: Thanks, I did some more research in the openssl x509 man pages and there is the destincition between -signkey and -CAkey, so I figured it was along this line and then your answer confirmed that. Thank you.